# "Unable to Connect to World" Hosted Minecraft server w/Minecraft PE iOS

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

- Minecraft 0.15.0 on iOS
- Minecraft server 1.10.2 (minecraft_server.1.10.2.jar)
- EC2 Amazon Linux
- Pixelmon mod

I am able to telnet to the Minecraft server and I can tell the network path is open.

However if I try to connect using Minecraft PE on iOS I get : "Unable to connect to world".

Is there a way to enable debug logs that will show connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a thread I posted here:

https://forums.imagicalmine.net/threads/official-minecraft-pe-server.1530/#post-15253

Minecraft PE is totally different from the server that is used for Xbox and the PC.  I was able to run Genisys and connect to it from my iOS device.

https://github.com/iTXTech/Genisys